# How fast can you go over speed breakers?

Tags: safety, hybrid-bike, road

so I've only recently started biking. I have a hybrid, [Montra Trance Pro](https://montra.in/bikes/hybrid-bike/2015-montra-trance-pro-2015).

So I went pretty fast over a few speed breakers, and that made me wonder, exactly how fast can I go over a bump? The rear derailleur especially seems really vulnerable to me. Am I just overthinking this, or should I slow down?

On my old gearless cycle, I wouldn't have thought twice over going fast over a speed breaker (not fast enough to lose control), but this new bike has me a bit worried.

Comment: It's a bump, no different from any other bump.  And the difference between speed bumps in different locations is enormous, so there's no way to give a general rule (eg, "7 mph"), even if the variables of bike and rider were not thrown in.  But, in general, if it doesn't throw you off the bike or shake your teeth out it's not going to hurt the bike.

Comment: I find it helps a lot to get out of the saddle.  Your weight can travel in a straight line while the wheels bump up and down.  Flexing your arms and legs seems to come naturally.

Comment: Even just in the once local council area I live in we have some short, steep speed bumps that act like half-height kerbs and I either bunny hop them or slow right down, through to others that are very gentle, while they are possibly the same 10cm or so height, they are more of a dome shape over a metre long so I don't slow down for them although I do unweight the saddle a little.

Comment: If your derailler is at risk of hitting the ground when passing over a speed bump (hump / sleeping policeman) then you're doing something wrong.   I use the bunny hop to get over single speed bumps, and cattle stops if going fast enough.  However I don't yet have a good technique for dual speed bumps... that tends to devolve into two bunnyhops in a row with a wheel on either side of the second bump.

Comment: HAHAHA I clicked your link and thought the loading animation was the bike to which you were referring.  +1 for inadvertent humour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a decent bike such as the one you linked to, it's not so much a question whether the bike can handle it, but it depends on how much *you* can handle.

How fast you can go over a bump depends a lot on your riding technique: if you are able to shift your weight in the right way you can significantly increase the speed to go over the bump. If you are able to do a [bunny hop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunny_hop_%28cycling%29) and jump over the bump, there's basically no upper speed limit. If you are worrying about the derailleur, there will be some noise from the chain clonking against the chain stay. However, a derailleur is built to handle such loads without any problems.

So yes, I guess you are overthinking this one.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, it was the sound of the derailleur that worried me really. Good to know I don't have to worry about that :)

Comment: @AneeshBarthakur - Yeah, on certain bikes you might get a sound from the chain whipping up and down, and, worst case, this could throw the chain off.  But that's probably the biggest hazard.

Comment: The first thing is to get off the seat. Then, if you can't bunny hop, lift the front wheel as you get to the bump.

Answer (score 3):

Down the road from me is a long road with two humps, I go down hill and the first has a gentle slope, I've never done less than full speed pedalling like a maniac over it. The other is steep, my strategy is to either jump it, or hit it on an angle standing with knees flexed and loose body to take the impact, the only speed difference (these are both down a hill) is I don't pedal while going over it.

I've been doing this for 6 months now every day and had no issues.

Comment: Must be a mountain bike your bike ? If I go downhill pedaling like a maniac into something similar on my road bike i'll be sent to stratosphere

Comment: Yep, it's a mountain bike, big heavy one at that.